# Create transparent image after using clipPath on ImageMagick v7

Tags: php, imagemagick

On ImageMagick v6 I used following code to create a transparent image with a clippath:

```
try {
    $im = new Imagick($image);
    $tmpOut = $im->identifyImage(TRUE);
    
    if(isset($tmpOut["rawOutput"]) AND strpos($tmpOut["rawOutput"], "Clipping path:") !== FALSE) {
        $im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_TRANSPARENT);
        $im->clipImage();
        $im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_OPAQUE);
    }
    $im->writeImage($pathSave . $filename);
    $im->destroy();
} catch (ImagickException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Since the version 7 I get following error:

```
Undefined class constant 'ALPHACHANNEL_OPAQUE'
```

I've already searched and the equivalent should be:

```
Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_OFF
```

But when I use this, the background is white and not transparent like before with version 6 of ImageMagick.

Maybe some of you were running into this situation and know a fix for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with `shell_exec` and added a check if the variable exist for my linux system where imagemagick version 6 is active. And changed `$im->destroy()` to `$im->clear()` because destroy is deprecated

My new code looks like:

```
try {
    $im = new Imagick($image);
    $tmpOut = $im->identifyImage(TRUE);

    if(isset($tmpOut["rawOutput"]) AND strpos($tmpOut["rawOutput"], "Clipping path:") !== FALSE) {
        if(defined('Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_OPAQUE')) {
            $im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_TRANSPARENT);
            $im->clipImage();
            $im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_OPAQUE);
        } else {
            $im->clear();
            $im = null;
            shell_exec("magick {$image} -alpha opaque -clip -alpha transparent +clip {$pathSave}{$filename}");
        }
    }
    
    if($im !== null) {
        $im->writeImage($pathSave . $filename);
        $im->clear();
        $im = null;
    }
} catch (ImagickException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```